# I use "onclick" function to simulate click color picker but it doesn't work . Windows and android are work well , only ios doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

I want to simulate click color picker ,when I test it on ios ,it doesn't work. I try simulate click input submit, it's work. Then I changed another color picker(jscolor), He can only work by clicking directly, He can't simulate click work by using other buttons. All the problem is on the ios, conputer and android don't have this question.
This is the Minimal code so you can Reproduce the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
        function gg() {
            document.getElementById('ssw').click();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="ssss" onclick="gg()">
<br><br>
<input type="color" id="ssw">
</body>
</html>
```

On ios I can't trigger the color picker by clicking this button(ssss), I want to hide the color picker and use other button to trigger color picker,of coure it's failed.

I try the fastclick.js to fix 300ms delay on ios , but it no use . I am a novice , This problem has plagued for several days ,Thank you for helping me check the problem .

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74511391/open-input-color-programatically-in-ios/74512068 