# Open input color programatically in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, color-picker

I noticed that in IOS I can't open the color picker of the default brower input programmatically. It works on desktop versions, and on other mobiles. Does anyone knows how I can fix the issue in IOS (Ipad, Iphones) ?

The following code reproduce the issue :

```js
function onClick() {
    document.getElementById('picker').click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onClick()">
  Open Color Picker
</button>

<br>

<input type="color" id="picker">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for the issue. I'm using a label linked to the input, and I trigger the label's click instead of the input one.

```js
function onClick() {
    document.getElementById('label').click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onClick()">
  Open Color Picker
</button>

<label id="label" for="picker"></label>

<br>

<input type="color" id="picker">
```